# How to have a design of the upload button inside the circle in the website either using: bootstrap, React, materialUI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

This is how It must looks like:

[here is the image , circle is a place where phtoto must be uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySeUQ.png)

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row mx-auto">
        <div class="col ">
            <span class="border border-success rounded-circle">
                <button class="btnUpload">
                    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: use "className" instead of "class" when working with react. To your problem: span is an inline element and doesn't have border. Turn it into a block element by setting display to block or use div element instead. Then center button vertically and horizontally inside of it, for example with flexbox:

```
<div
  className="border border-success rounded-circle"
  style={{ width: 100, height: 100, margin: 50 }}
>
  <div className="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <button className="btnUpload">
      <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/white-http-wsy881